# How come Django QuerySet returns more values than number of objects in database (repeated objects)?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm, django-queryset

I am attempting to run a complex query with Django.
The below query should return an ordered queryset where the users with the most resources as well as resources that contain same tags to the ones in "common_tags" list should show up on top.

**The code is below:**

```
    is_in_query = Q(resources__tags__name__in=common_tags)
    is_not_in_query = ~Q(resources__tags__name__in=common_tags)

    #All user count is used to compare number of objects
    all_user_count = User.objects.filter(is_private=False)

    #len(qs_full) should equal len(all_user_count)
    qs_full = (User.objects.filter(is_private=False).annotate(count_resources=Count('resources'))
    .annotate(
    search_type_ordering=Case(
    When(Q(count_resources__gte=6) & is_in_query, then=1),
    When(Q(count_resources__gte=3) & Q(count_resources__lte=5) & is_in_query, then=2),
    When(Q(count_resources__gte=0) & Q(count_resources__lte=2) & is_in_query, then=3),
    When(Q(count_resources__gte=3) & is_not_in_query, then=4),
    When(Q(count_resources__gte=0) & Q(count_resources__lte=2) & is_not_in_query, then=5),
    default=6,
    output_field=IntegerField(),
    ))
    .order_by('-search_type_ordering',)
    )
```

**The problem:**

The output of len(all_user_count) is 104.
The output of len(qs_full) is 128.

There are duplicates in qs_full. I do not know why.

Comment: My experience is that filtering across multiple models often results in duplicates (no specific experience with that in Case/When clause.  You might be able to call distinct on your queryset depending on your database type.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried distinct() and it doesn't work in this scenario.

Comment: What parameters did you pass to distinct?  If you did order_by('-search_type_ordering', 'id').distinct('search_type_ordering', 'id'), I would think it would drop those duplicated Users.

Comment: My database is unable to take parameters in distinct.